# Calculating Fisher's exact test for COG categories

Tags: statistics, eggnog, pangenome

This is a continuation of the following question -

[Fisher's exact test for COG categories in pan, core genome analysis](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/22104/fishers-exact-test-for-cog-categories-in-pan-core-genome-analysis/22108)

Also, the dataset -

[image: COG categories dataset]

How do I perform a Fisher's exact test on this data to show that a COG category is significantly more or less in the pan/core/accessory/species specific genomes?

Comment: I'll post a response late Monday, sorry really busy. Basically you can do spot checks via Fishers Exact test or go the whole hog and do a Chi2 test. The matrix you have is pan/core vs cogs.

Comment: Hi @M__, good to know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would personally do is run a Χ<sup>2</sup>

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
import numpy as np

pan = [11, 39, 4 ....]
core = [29, 50, 7 ... ]
f_exp = np.array(pan)
f_obs = np. array(core)
print (chisquare(f_obs=f_obs, f_exp=f_exp))
```

This will output the total statistic and whether its above or below the critical probability.

Fisher's Exact test is essentially Χ<sup>2</sup> for a small number of observations, which is not the case with your data.

Looking at your data Χ<sup>2</sup> is not likely to be "significant" (which is the result you are looking for), i.e. the pan genome is the core genome across all COGs.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your efforts @M__ ! Hopefully, this works.